# AX2012 - Pre-Processed RecId parameter not found

Tags: reporting, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I made a custom report in AX2012, to replace the WHS Shipping pick list. The custom report is RDP based. I have no trouble running it directly (with the parameters dialog), but when I try to use the controller (WHSPickListShippingController), I get an error saying "Pre-Processed RecId not found. Cannot process report. Indicates a development error."

The error is because in the class SrsReportProviderQueryBuilder (setArgs method), the map variable reportProviderParameters is empty. I have no idea why that is. The code in my Data provider runs okay. Here is my code for running the report :

```
WHSWorkId id = 'LAM-000052';
WHSPickListShippingController controller;
Args args;
WHSShipmentTable whsShipmentTable;
WHSWorkTable whsWorkTable;
clWHSPickListShippingContract contract; //My custom RDP Contract  

whsShipmentTable = WHSShipmentTable::find(whsWorkTable.ShipmentId);

args = new Args(ssrsReportStr(WHSPickListShipping, Report));
args.record(whsShipmentTable);
args.parm(whsShipmentTable.LoadId);

contract = new clWHSPickListShippingContract();

controller = new WHSPickListShippingController();
controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(WHSPickListShipping, Report));
controller.parmShowDialog(false);
controller.parmLoadFromSysLastValue(false);
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(contract);
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpName(classStr(clWHSPickListShippingDP));
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdlContract().parmLanguageId(CompanyInfo::languageId());
controller.parmArgs(args);

controller.startOperation();
```

I don't know if I'm clear enough... But I've been looking for a fix for hours without success, so I thought I'd ask here. Is there a reason why this variable (which comes from the method parameter AifQueryBuilderArgs) would be empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so now I feel very stupid for spending so much time on that error, when it's such a tiny thing...

The erronous line is that one :

```
controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(WHSPickListShipping, Report));
```

Because WHSPickListShipping is the name of the AX report, but I renamed my custom report clWHSPickListShipping. What confused me was that my DataProvider class was executing as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your issue is with these lines (try removing):

```
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(contract);
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpName(classStr(clWHSPickListShippingDP));
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdlContract().parmLanguageId(CompanyInfo::languageId());
```

The style I'd expect to see with your contract would be like this:

```
controller = new WHSPickListShippingController();
contract = controller.getDataContractObject();
contract.parmWhatever('ParametersHere');
controller.parmArgs(args);
```

And for the DataProvider `clWHSPickListShippingDP`, usually if a report is using a DataProvider, you don't manually set it, but the DP extends `SRSReportDataProviderBase` and has an attribute `SRSReportParameterAttribute(...)` decorating the class declaration in this style:

```
[SRSReportParameterAttribute(classstr(MyCustomContract))]
class MyCustomDP extends SRSReportDataProviderBase
{
    // Vars
}
```

You are using `controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(contract);` wrong, as this is more for run-time modifications.  It's typically used for accessing the contract for `preRunModifyContract` overloads.

Build your CrossReference in a development environment then right click on `\Classes\SrsReportDataContract\parmRdpContract` and click `Add-Ins>Cross-reference>Used By` to see how that is generally used.

Comment: Alright, so I tried that, without success... First, if I remove the line setting the parmRdpName, my DataProvider doesn't run. And removing the other two lines doesn't seem to change anything, I still get the same error. Also, my DP extends SrsReportDataProviderPreProcess and the SRSReportParameterAttribute is present.

Comment: Ok so I found what was wrong. My mistake, nobody could have found it since that part of my code was not in my question. I would still upvote your answer since you taught me something I didn't know, but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Glad you figured it out and hopefully I helped the overall process!